# Is there a way to retrieve mobile screen dimensions in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mobile

Can I retrieve the height of the user's mobile screen?

We want to dynamically set the number of items displayed per page.

Comment: I think the best way will be to use. Javascript width and height. Will only work if browser supports javascript.

Comment: @EmmanuelN - We want to limit the number of results on the server side. Short of an AJAX call, there is nowhere to retrieve the height on the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVC no, This is a function of the browser and  script support
See: http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech3.shtml

Comment: So there is no way to retrieve this value in the action itself?

Comment: no, the action is all purely server side and has no idea what client will be viewing this. You can though use media types in css to help with different layouts here if thats what you want.  http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/04/targeted-css/  however since it seems you want to limit results, you can detect certain browsers (all the main mobile ones) on the server side by the user agent string. Check out: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/12/17/using-51degreesmobi-foundation-for-accurate-mobile-browser-detection-on-aspnet-mvc-3/  and then its easy to detect simply 'mobile'

Comment: @ShaiCohen The javascript could "inject" the screen dimensions in the query string... so that once the user clic on some link, the dimension is poster to the controller action.